# ANSA Automation using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, automation, scripting

I am trying to write a script in ANSA using python.
The script should compare the results of different user script buttons and I need to automate the process.
The ideal steps for the script will be:
Launch ansa through the terminal, load the model on which a user script button has to be applied. Take the same model in a newer version and apply the same user script button and then compare them using the compare tool in ansa. Any help with the scripting would be tremendous!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I am sorry for my vague explanation. I am trying to compare two models in ansa from their different versions (v17 and v20). On both models, a similar user script button has been applied. Now, what I want to perform is a compare function.
According to Ansa user guide, I could find base.compare function, but I am not able to understand how to code a script where I could use this function and also save the comparison results as a pdf file.
Lets, say I have two models: Model_1 and Model_2 and these need to compared using python script and functions from Ansa Library

Comment: Hi @Shrey Agrawal you cant load lower version ansa model in same ansa. we can load one step older version but not more than that. example.  if you are using 21version ansa, you can load 21 and 20 version files . you cant load 19,18,17 version files